# Change the form of a shape

Tags: c++, objective-c, shapes, stretch

How to change the form of a shape by stretching it out in different directions, without the perimeter changing? take a piece of string with both ends connected as an example, it would form a shape resembling a circle, if one side is pushed in or out, only the shape will change, but the perimeter and area will stay the same. Im trying to accomplish something almost if not identical to this.

I am not sure if I am being very clear with my question, please let me know if it needs to be given more detail. Any help would be appreciated.

Even though this is needed for an application written in objective-c, code in C, C++, or C# will also be of help.

Comment: This looks more like a math/geometry problem, so you might better ask at http://math.stackexchange.com. - Preserving both perimeter and area might be difficult or impossible.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.  preserving the area/perimeter should not be a requirement.  Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a collection of points,p, that represent the convex hull of your object, that which your string would rest against. You provided a constraint such that the total perimeter is to be constant, but without giving more info, there are a multitude of ways those points could be rearranged given your single constraint.

Take a triangle for example, if I pull a point away from the centroid of the triangle, should the other 2 vertices simply move closer together, or should 1 move closer to the pulled vertex.

I would suggest looking into spring based particles, which is how cloth and rope are simulated in video games.

Comment: Well, let's say I have a collection of points that makes the border of an irregular image. I want to resize the border (with a finger on an iPad). It's the same effect as when I have a round string on a table and, with the finger, I change it's shape. I have already implemented an algorithm to detect when the finger touches the border now I need an algorithm to drag the touched point at the border an change the border's shape

Comment: I understand your question, but I don't think you understood my response. There are multiple solutions to your problem. If you collection of points define a equilateral triangle, with a perimeter of 3, and you pull 1 point away from the center. One solution is to constrain the distances between that vertex and the other 2 as well as the angle created by those edges. This will simply drag those 2 points along with the first. this is not what you want.

Comment: Another solution would be to constrain the distances, but not the angles.  As you pull the point out, the other 2 vertices would move closer together(the edge between them would shrink) to account for the increased length of the other 2 edges.

Comment: As I said in my original post, what you should look at is a spring based particle system, such as the one described here. Http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/particle/ You do not need to worry about gravity, but you do need to use hook's law to resolve the tension of the system, preferably through multiple iterations.

Comment: I will check that article out and see if it's helps my problem. thank you for your comments